# Use a function to handle a negative offset

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, offset, plpgsql

I am creating a Postgresql function in order to handle a negative offset. When the offset is negative then my function should return 0. However, when I try to run this function, there is an error near "row", I am not sure why. What is wrong with my conditional branch?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
    calc_offset(row integer, padding integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
    BEGIN
        if (row-1-padding) < 0 then return 0;
        else return (row-1-padding);
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

WITH all_the_trimmings AS (
    SELECT ui.id, ui.name, ui.time, 
           row_number() over(order by name asc) as rownumber
    FROM user_infos ui

  ), my_row AS (
    SELECT * FROM all_the_trimmings WHERE id=1
  ), the_slice AS (
    SELECT * FROM all_the_trimmings LIMIT 5 
       OFFSET calc_offset((SELECT rownumber FROM my_row)::int,2)
  )
SELECT * from my_row
UNION ALL
SELECT * from the_slice;
```

[SQL fiddle for the full picture](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cf2d6/35)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row parameter is a reserved word. Try replacing it with another name. You were also missing an end if;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
    calc_offset(p_row integer, padding integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
    BEGIN
        if (p_row-1-padding) < 0 then 
          return 0;
        else
          return (p_row-1-padding);
        end if;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I added your code but I get a new error.  Something about an unquoted string near begin and the $$.  [See the error here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cf2d6/47)

Comment: So it looks like sometimes the stuff between the two $$ need to be done on one line.  I made that conditional statement into one line and it appears to be working alright.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `calc_offset()` can be replaced with this simple SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_offset(p_row int, padding int)
  RETURNS int AS 'SELECT GREATEST ($1 - $2 - 1, 0)' LANGUAGE sql;
```

And you don't need the function *at all*. Just use [**`GREATEST`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) with a subselect:

```
WITH all_the_trimmings AS (
   SELECT ui.id, ui.name, ui.time, row_number()  OVER (ORDER BY name) AS rn
   FROM   user_infos ui
   )
, my_row AS (
   SELECT * FROM all_the_trimmings WHERE id=1
   )
SELECT * FROM my_row
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM all_the_trimmings LIMIT 5 
OFFSET GREATEST ((SELECT rn - 3 FROM my_row), 0);
```

Or simpler:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT ui.id, ui.name, ui.time, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS rn
   FROM   user_infos ui
   )
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cte LIMIT 5 
OFFSET GREATEST ((SELECT rn - 3 FROM cte WHERE id = 1), 0);
```

[SQL Fiddle showing both.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cf2d6/61)